# Can I set a maximum volume in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, audio

A member of my household often sets the volume on his Mac too loud, annoying the rest of the family.  We're all getting tired of asking him to turn it down.

Is there any way to set a maximum volume level that can't be exceeded without administrator-level access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a freeware app [Volimiter](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/Volimiter.shtml) that'll do this. The posted version seems to be for Tiger, so if you're using Leopard / Snow Leopard YMMV.

Comment: As it happens, the offender's machine is currently running Tiger, so this may be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it yourself using Apple's script editor.

You can create a script in Javascript like this

```
    class Volimiter {
      constructor(appName, maxVolume) {
        this.app = Application.currentApplication();
        this.app.includeStandardAdditions = true;
        this.appName = appName;
        this.maxVolume = maxVolume;
      }

      get currentVolume() {
        const { outputVolume } = this.app.getVolumeSettings();
        return outputVolume;
      }

      limitVolume() {
        if (this.currentVolume > this.maxVolume) {
          this.app.beep();
          this.app.setVolume(null, { outputVolume: this.maxVolume });
        }
      }

      showNotification() {
        this.app.displayNotification("", {
          withTitle: this.appName,
          subtitle: `Limiting your  volume to ${
            this.maxVolume
          }% to protect your ears`
        });
      }
    }

    const PurrfectVolume = new Volimiter("Purrfect volume ", 25);
    PurrfectVolume.showNotification();

    function idle() {
      PurrfectVolume.limitVolume();
      return 0.5;
    }
```

This will limit your volume to the one you set in maxVolume in line `const PurrfectVolume = new Volimiter("Purrfect volume ", 25);`. 
It will check your volume level every half a second and if the volume higher it will "ping", show a notification and set it again on your volume limit.

If you delete lines 21-28 (showNotification method) and line 32 (its call) it won't show the notification. If you delete line 16 it won't beep and nobody will notice.

I wrote about it [here](https://medium.com/trabe/limiting-your-macs-volume-in-2019-f314e20408ab). And even made a downloadable script in case you don't know how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is still relevant, there is an app I wrote, it's called [Earsafe](https://earsafe.io).

Although you can't restrict the access of the limit just yet, but I'm planning to add that feature to it.